# Fedora 30 freezed

Tags: linux, fedora, freeze

I'm running 32 bit Fedora 30 on a ASUS laptop, with xfce4, systemd, etc. Sometimes, the system freezes, the mouse has no more influence. I cannot switch to a console using Crtl-Alt-F#. I'm not sure if this is related to a mouse mouving. No message on the screen. I'm only able to shutdown after a long pressing of the power-on button.

After rebooting in the single user mode, I cannot find anything in the /var/log directory which can give me any information about an occured error. When examining the log using journalctl, I can see the last entries of the previous boot: "systemd-logind []: Power key pressed" resulting from my short pressing of this key in the attempt to get the attention of the system. I conclude that the system was not completly dead, but nothing was accepted from the keybord. On this laptop, nearly everything is entered via the keyboard, the power key is the only exception.

Because of the lack of information about this situation, I wish to collect a good amount of information when this bad situation will occur again. I my opinion, I think that the pressing of the power should be used to trigger a system status dump into a diskfile. I will probably have to replace temporarilly the /etc/acpi/actions/power.sh by a special file which should trigger this status request.

What do you suggest me to include in this file ? What is your opinion about this way ? Do you have a better suggestion ?

Comment: Can you `ssh` into the machine when it "freezes"?

Comment: I'm not sure if ssh is possible because the machine is a laptop with not responding keyboard. The only possibility to try can be via the network, but I have not tried it.

Comment: That's why I'm wondering if you could `ssh` into the laptop from another machine... the laptop's keyboard would be irrelevant and you may be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: BTW, all your packages have the latest versions, yes? `sudo dnf upgrade`

Comment: Also wondering if you create a new user account, will it not have the same symptoms? I.e., create a new user account, login to the new user account and use it normally. If it doesn't freeze, maybe there is something in the original user's configuration that is causing the problem.

Comment: Errors in the user settings should not produce a crash and segfault of libglib. Yes, all available upgrades are applied.

Comment: I suspect that the last upgrade to glib2-2.60.7-3.fc30.i686 has introduced the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I have tried to logon in via ssh, in such a freeze situation. This was successful and the system was running well, as I could see. At the end of the dmesg output, I see the following interesting lines:

[13297.745859] show_signal_msg: 3 callbacks suppressed
[13297.745863] gdbus[3664]: segfault at 6 ip b6fe2bf4 sp b55febe0 error 4 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6000.7[b6f8e000+86000]
[13297.745876] Code: 10 e9 b2 fe ff ff c1 ea 03 8b 2f 8d 4a ff 89 54 24 0c 8d 04 cd 00 00 00 00 01 c5 89 44 24 08 8b 75 00 85 f6 0f 84 ac 00 00 00 <8b> 46 04 85 c0 74 35 8b 10 89 56 04 89 c6 8b 45 04 85 c0 74 06 83

Because Fedora 30 is at the end of life now, it's probably not useful to report this problem via Bugzilla.

**Addition:**

After I have opened a session from another computer using ssh, I was surprised to see a system running "normally". Only on some occasions, I could find error messages using **dmesg** or **journalctl** and these messages were different, not allowing to point to the source of the freezed screen and keyboard. While trying to stop the display manager using "systemctl stop lightdm", I observed that **Xorg** and its thread **libinput** were freezed, not responding to any TERM or KILL signal. I concluded that **libinput** is probably the source of the problem. Considering that **evdev** is available on this system, I have decided to replace libinput by evdev, inserting this link:

```
ln -s /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
```

After this insertion and after the restart, the reported freezing did not more appeared.

**Further addition:**

Unfortunately, the problem has returned in the same manner as before.

Comment: Same/similar to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1706433 ?